# Select statement in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, select

I have the following table `user`,I want to select group_id from the table but when I execute the following query it gives me an error

[image]**Query** :

```
select u.name,u.group_id  from user u
```

**Error** :

> column u.group_id does not exist

How can I select group id from the table?

Comment: The name would appear to have hidden characters in it.

Comment: or you have same table names on different schema and didn't notice

Answer (score 3):

`user` is a reserved keyword, you need to [use double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#sql-syntax-identifiers) in order to be able to use it:

```
select u.name, u.group_id
from "user" u;
```

But quoted identifiers will give you a lot of troubles in the long run, you should find a name that does not require the use of double quotes.

---

`user` is not only a reserved keyword, it's also a *function* which returns the currently logged in user. If you do not quote the keyword, Postgres assumes you mean the *function* `user`, e.g.: like this:

```
select * from user;
```

```
user  
--------------------
a_horse_with_no_name
```

That result apparently has no column named `group_id` (or `name` for that matter) and that's why you get the error.

Comment: It was my mistake i wrote 'user' instead of 'users'